# Golang and yaml with dynamic schema

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

I have a YAML structure with dynamic schema e.g. I can have the following yaml:

```
array:
  - name: myvar
    val: 1
  - name: mymap
    val: [ 1, 2]
```

Goyaml maps yaml to Go struct, which should declare definite type. Here, `val` is either a signle number, or an array or even a map.

Which is the best solution for this situation?

Comment: did you try `interface{}` as type for `val`?

Comment: Specifically, you would use `interface{}` for the type, then use a type switch (https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) to utilize it.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, TehSphinX thanks, aren't there any disadvantages of such approach?

Comment: I don't think there is another approach unless you change the yaml and give the variables different names. If you have a variable of type `interface{}` you will have to cast it depending on it's type later. That is a bit work but you are getting good suggestions on that below.

Comment: @TehSphinX Correct, dealing with `interface{}` values is kind of a pain, but the advantage with go is that it is statically typed, yet you can do this sort of pseudo loose typing. Gotta put in the extra effort to get it done though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to add an answer showing a type assertion instead of the `reflect` package. You can decide which is best for your application. I personally prefer the builtin functions over the complexity of the `reflect` package.

```
var data = `
array:
  - name: myvar
    val: 1
  - name: mymap
    val: [1, 2]
`

type Data struct {
    Array []struct {
        Name string
        Val  interface{}
    }
}

func main() {
    d := Data{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &d)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := range d.Array {
        switch val := d.Array[i].(type) {
        case int:
            fmt.Println(val) // is integer
        case []int:
            fmt.Println(val) // is []int
        case []string:
            fmt.Println(val) // is []string
            //  .... you get the idea
        default:
            log.Fatalf("Type unaccounted for: %+v\n", d.Array[i])
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: To make your answer perfect could you add the lines of how to cast `Val` of type `interface{}` to variables of type `int`, `[]int`, `[]string`, etc?

Comment: They **are** casted inside the switch statement. Inside their respective case `val` is actually of the correct type.

Comment: If you need to assert a single variable into something you know it should be (or you think haha), you can use a type assertion. https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Comment: `for i := range t.Array {` should be `for i := range d.Array {` no? Also, whats with the single char variable names in go?

Comment: @Steve thanks, I made some changes outside a code editor and that leaked through. Didn't help that there isn't a builtin `yaml` package, so I couldn't do a playground.